Tricky Problem - Vector Calculus
I think I was able to solve a somewhat tricky problem from this book
https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486466205
But I think I am seeing a small issue in the problem statement (but no the hint actually), so I want to confirm that part.
Here is a definition.

Note 1: Usually in such definitions the authors mean that the domain $D$ is open. They mentioned this even explicitly on page 113. So I am assuming here that $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^m}$.
Note 2: The wording of this definition is slightly strange, I am not sure btw if "such that" applies to the function $f$ or to the smooth surface $S$ which is being defined (or to both).
That problem below (3.8.10), it complements the theory because in the theoretical part of the text they say this.


OK, now the problem is stated as follows (exercise 3.8.10, page 152).

While solving the problem, I came to the conclusion that we cannot claim that $K$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^m}$. But still, we can prove that $D\setminus K$ is open in $\mathbb{R^m}$.
For example in $\mathbb{R^1}$, I think we can have a situation where $D=(1,5)$ but $K = (1,3]$. Right? My thought is this: as long as D and K have "a common" boundary point (like the point $x=1$ here), we cannot claim anything about that boundary point (i.e. we cannot claim it's in K), because it's not even in D.
I think even better examples are possible in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Say D - open circle, then K is also a circle "touching" D from within, say K contains all its boundary points except one point M, where M is "the touch point", so it's that boundary point which is not in K and is also not in D => in this example K is also not a closed set, right?

I think we can claim the following though: if p is a boundary point of K and p is also in D, then p is in K. I think I was able to prove that.
So am I right that we cannot claim that K is closed, at least not that it's closed in $\mathbb{R^m}$? Or did they mean maybe that K is closed in D? But if they meant that, then they cannot make easily the conclusion that $D \setminus K$ is open in $\mathbb{R^m}$, right?

The fact that $D - K$ is open in $D$ implies that it is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and this is easy to prove. Nevertheless, this does not imply that $K$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$; it only means that $K$ is closed in $D$. However, you only need the first fact mentioned to draw a conclusion.

In regard to your Note 2, "such that" is a very common expression used to impose conditions on newly introduced objects. I don't see what you might not be understanding exactly, but basically since both $f$ and $S$ are involved you could say it applies to both. Semantically I guess it applies to $f$ but whatever.

@BrunoB Yes, of course I know what it means, just didn't quite understand it in this particular definition.

OK... So is this really an issue in the Hint, i.e. am I correct in my statement above, that $K$ is not necessarily closed as the Hint claims?
